# How can I make page-specific reporting with Google Analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have many pages. I want to analyze each page privately.

I want to access the age, gender, phone model, network operator, browser and operating systems information of each page I want.

But google gives this information for the whole site.

Example;

example.com/page/XXX

example.com/page/YYY

example.com/page/ZZZ I need to get the statistics of 3 different pages like this separately.

**Important:** There is no such thing as creating new google analytics for each page. There are tens of thousands of pages.

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have socio-demographic information broken down by pages, they are based on a percentage of users and the data is aggregated.

To get the pages you need, instead of defining them one by one, you can find a rule and use a regex.